# OpenCV: Histogram not displaying correctly

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to plot Histogram of  lenna [here the 8 bit single ch. gray scale image](http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp).

[image]

But it is not displaying the output correctly, as can be seen in the following output:

```
void show_histogram_image(Mat img1)
{ 

   int sbins = 256;
   int histSize[] = {sbins};

   float sranges[] = { 0, 256 };
   const float* ranges[] = { sranges };
   cv::MatND hist;
   int channels[] = {0};

   cv::calcHist( &img1, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), // do not use mask
       hist, 1, histSize, ranges,
       true, // the histogram is uniform
       false );

   double maxVal=0;
   minMaxLoc(hist, 0, &maxVal, 0, 0);

   int xscale = 10;
   int yscale = 10;


   cv::Mat hist_image; 
   hist_image = cv::Mat::zeros(256, sbins*xscale, CV_8UC1);

   for( int s = 0; s < sbins; s++ )
   {
       float binVal = hist.at<float>(s, 0);
       int intensity = cvRound(binVal*255/maxVal);

      rectangle( hist_image, cv::Point(s*xscale, 0),
           cv::Point( (s+1)*xscale - 1, intensity),
           cv::Scalar::all(255),
           CV_FILLED );

           }

        imshow("Image1",hist_image);


 waitKey(0); 

}
```

Here is my main();

```
int main()

{

    Mat img1 = imread("lena512.bmp", CV_8UC1);


         if (img1.empty()) //check whether the image is valid or not 
         {
              cout << "Error : Image cannot be read..!!" << endl;
              system("pause"); //wait for a key press
              return -1;
         }



    show_histogram_image(img1); 

}
```

And here is the output Histogram image:

[image]

I tried changing the xscale even then it is not coming correctly.

**Update**

I made the following changes:

```
rectangle( hist_image, cv::Point(s*xscale, hist_image.rows), 
          cv::Point( (s+1)*xscale - 1, hist_image.rows - intensity), 
          cv::Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED );
```

And now the output is:

[image]

It is much better , but I need lines and clearly visible bins. And it looks like some part is hidden on the right side.

**Update 2**

I changed CV_FILLED to '1' and now I have:

[image]

Comment: it's just upside down, since image origin is top-left and y-axis is pointing down

Comment: @berak so you want me to rotate this at 180 degree? Even then it would be meaningless

Comment: no, more like image.rows-y for the points

Comment: @berak Did not get. Sorry

Comment: rectangle( hist_image, cv::Point(s*xscale, hist_image.rows), cv::Point( (s+1)*xscale - 1, hist_image.rows - intensity), cv::Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED );

Comment: @berak Thanks. If you can put this as an answer, it would be more visible to me and others , who might want to use it or improve it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the image origin in opencv is (0,0), and thus the y-axis is pointing downwards,
you will have to invert the y-values for your histogram-drawing:

```
rectangle( hist_image, cv::Point(s*xscale, hist_image.rows),
       cv::Point( (s+1)*xscale - 1, hist_image.rows - intensity),
       cv::Scalar::all(255),
       CV_FILLED );
```

Comment: so basically I want to have vertical lines at the boundary of each bin.

Comment: change CV_FILLED to something else ?

Comment: one general question. Do I need to invert Y-values in every case. For example if I am plotting pixel values across any line, do I need to invert Y-values ?

Comment: hmm, probably depends. yes, if you're plotting some function, no, if you're doing something aligned to the image

Comment: I tried the same code on a 16 bit per pixel image. It is not displaying anything. I replaced 256 everywhere with 65536, and 255 by 65535, also I changed in Zeros() CV_8UC1 to CV_16UC1. A big black window opens , and nothing is displayed. Any comments

Comment: oh, keep the drawing image 8bit, else you have to use cv::Scalar::all(65536) for white color. 255 is in the 16bit world, what 1 is in the 8bit world - barely visible.